# dropping rows from dataframe when column contains a decimal value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the column `SimTime`, which has values like

```
SimTime
0
2
4
4.4
6
6.4
8
```

I only want to keep values which are integers and I am using the following snippet, however, I'm unable to see any changes in the dataframe.

```
df=df.drop(df.index[(df['SimTime']%1).astype(int)!=0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare values converted to integers in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.SimTime==df.SimTime.astype(int)]
```

Your solution is with compare by `0` instead droping by index if comapre for not equal `0`:

```
df1 = df[(df['SimTime']%1).eq(0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works, you just have the `astype` method in the wrong place. It should be:

```py
df = df.drop(df.index[df['SimTime'] % 1 != 0]).astype(int)
```

But in case there is more than one column in the dataframe, you may want to convert just the one column to integer:

```py
df.drop(df.index[df['SimTime'] % 1 != 0], inplace=True)
df['SimTime'] = df['SimTime'].astype(int)
```